# MVVM RaisePropertyChanged implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a small tool which should display a list of servers to learn MVVM. I'm using MVVM Light and some tutorials (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Let's say I have a class called Server which has the properties IP, Name and Ping. These values are not touched from outside so I set the setter to private. These properties are updated every ten seconds by a background thread querying the data from the server (it's a steam server). Now I also implemented a view for this which looks like this.

```
public class ServerViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    private Server server;

    public Server Server
    {
        get
        {
            return server;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.Name;
        }
    }

    public int Ping
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.Ping;
        }
    }

    public int PlayerCount
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.PlayerCount;
        }
    }

    public int MaxPlayers
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.MaxPlayers;
        }
    }

    public ServerViewModel(Server server)
    {
        this.server = server;
    }
}
```

This ViewModel is managed by another ViewModel called ServersView:

```
public class ServersViewModel
{
  #region Members

  ObservableCollection<ServerViewModel> servers = new ObservableCollection<ServerViewModel>();

  #endregion

  #region Properties
  public ObservableCollection<ServerViewModel> Servers
  {
      get
      {
          return servers;
      }

      set
      {
          servers = value;
      }
  }
  #endregion

  #region Construction
  public ServersViewModel()
  {
      Model.Server.Servers serversInstance = new Model.Server.Servers();
      foreach(IServer current in serversInstance.ServerList)
      {
          if(current is Server)
          {
              servers.Add(new ServerViewModel((Server) current));
          }                
      }            
  }
  #endregion
}
```

Now my question is where to implement the RaisePropertyChanged method. Should I do this directly in the Server class, ServerView or in the ServersView? Also I want to have a user control per server added to a simple grid. How could I realize this?

Comment: Does your observable object class implement INotifyPropertyChanged? if so it should be implemented there. Since you are using private setters but are still updating the values, when you update the values you will have to call raise property changed in whatever method is doing the updating

Comment: Yes it does. I just looked at the definition.

Comment: It likely already implements the RaisePropertyChanged method in that case, but check the code/docs to be sure. In that case you just call it (with the proper parameter) whenever you update data that the ui is directly using

Comment: Yeah it's also implementing the RaisePropertyChanged method. Means that I would call it in Server class in the setter?

Comment: Implement INPC everywhere.  Bind your collection of ServerViewModels to an ItemsControl. Create a DataTemplate to display the contents of each ServerViewModel. And for god's sake create a small prototype to do this so you can learn how it works before trying to implement it in a more complex application.

Comment: I'm doing this step by step. I already made small projects but never ever did data binding in such a context.